# How to exclude files in Jenkins ArtifactDeployer plugin?

Tags: jenkins, artifacts

Right now this is what I have for the project. How can I exclude a particular dll from being copied?

```
Artifacts to deploy : **\*.*
Artifacts to deploy Basedir:    ${WORKSPACE}\CRDAdapter\CRDAdapter\bin
Remote File Location
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd *Advanced* Button will open a form where you can specify excludes.

[image]